# Which ArcGIS SDK to use ArcSDE SDK, ArcGIS Runtime SDK, ArcObjects SDK?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, arcgis-runtime

I have a geodatabase on SQL Server 2008 R2 and ArcGIS 10.2.2 installed. Both are on my local computer.

I will interface to a Delphi Application and my aim is to query some records/fields line by line, not as a map layer directly.

I didnot find ArcObjects SDK and then installed runtime SDK for .NET. I investigated their samples in C# and I didnot find an entry point for an SQL Server database connection, query table data etc.
(Closest solution was an enterprise portal approach based on their WebGIS online url address)

I am sorry that I am new in ArcGIS products and confused now which SDK for ArcGIS 10.2.2 I should use and how to get it. ArcSDE SDK, ArcGIS Runtime SDK, ArcObjects SDK, which version?

It would be very helpful to get some ideas especially about which SDK and where to get free etc..

Comment: You *don't* want to use the ArcSDE API, so take that off your list.  Replace it with an ODBC connection to the database.

Comment: Thanks Thad, I installed the ArcObjects SDK as you said.
Made connection to database and got the desired results :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install the ArcObjects SDK to work with your enterprise geodatabases. If you have ArcGIS, the SDK is available to you as a separate install. You can find it either on your installation DVD (if you have one) or for download from the customer service site. Please see the links below for more info.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/arcgis-desktop/10.2/index.html#//008700000003000000

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/34418